# Load git repo with composer - autoloading issue

Tags: php, git, composer-php, autoloader

I have a github repository https://github.com/KoulSlou/UPS and I would like to add it to my project.

In project root I created composer.json file and defined the following autoloading properties:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "libraries/Ups/Ups.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Base.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Base_Response.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Live_Rates.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run

```
php composer.phar install
```

repository is being downloaded, but it looks like autoloader is not working. When I try to initialize one of the classes

```
$test = new Ups()
```

I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Ups' not found in application/....
```

Did I define "autoload" property incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I have found out what was the problem. composer.json file in the project I was trying to load - [UPS library](https://github.com/KoulSlou/UPS) -was invalid. I was able to download files when I ran:

```
composer.phar install
```

but it looks like composer.json file was ignored. I found it out when I ran

```
composer.phar update
```

and got

```
No valid composer.json was found
```

With option -v I got error that "name" is undefined index. So, I simply added "name" field to the composer.json. Final version is:

```
{
    "name":"KoulSlou/UPS",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "libraries/Ups/Ups.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Base.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Base_Response.php",
            "libraries/Ups/Ups_Live_Rates.php"
         ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using the "files" autoloader, because that isn't very automatic - the files mentioned here are ALWAYS included. Replacing it with "classmap" would be better. And then you'd not be required to mention ALL files, but you can simply state the directory you want to have scanned for classes.

Now what I don't see anywhere: Did you initialize Composer's autoloader anywhere? This usually is something like

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Comment: Yes, I have this line "require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/../vendor/autoload.php';" in my index.php file (I'm using Zend Framework). Other composer packages has been uploaded successfully, but with my github repo I receive this fatal error.

Comment: At first glance, everything you did looks ok to me, even with the "files" autoload definition, and including the autoloading before using the class. However, if it still doesn't work, something is broken somewhere. Have you tried adding a `die('here');` statement in the code path you assume will be taken? The script should stop and echo the text. I'd add such a die right at the start of the "Ups" file to ensure this file gets loaded, and then move it around to see which parts of the code get executed. Additionally, make sure `display_errors` is on and `error_reporting` is at maximum "E_ALL".